# How to add a record to a domain on GCP App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have a domain given by GCP myDomain.appspot.com by default.
I need to add a record to redirect 'www' subdomain to an IP adress. (www used for an API connection)
Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a custom domain and subdomains via App Engine settings in the console. The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mapping-custom-domains) gives step by step instructions on how to do it. Then you can use a [dispatch.yaml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/reference/dispatch-yaml) file to map requests to a specific service of your app.

However there's [no way to map static IP addresses](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/kb/?hl=en#static-ip) to an application. This is because App Engine services use a pool of IP addresses that are subject to change over time.